# Why Fancybox doesn't work with SpriteSpin

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-3

I use 2 JavaScript libs:

- SpriteSpin (http://spritespin.ginie.eu/),
- Fancybox (https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/)

But my script does't work: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle%20.%20net/EMDM/tq8407ud/3/)

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: You see, **linking** to a jsfiddle isn't enough. The relevant parts of your code, and error description should be part of this question here. And this site is English only. There is **zero** point in having Russian text here.

Answer (score 0):

fancybox can display any HTML, therefore statements like "Fancybox doesn't work with .. (insert any name here)" are misleading and wrong. And your snippet works fine, too, see this demo - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EdddPX

In your case, you just have to disable touch events, like so:

```
product3dGalleryButton.fancybox({
  touch : false
});
```

(and do not forget to include jQuery)